# Any idea which model & year my Giant bike is?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike, giant

I bought my giant bike a few months ago and want to sell it and upgrade. Do you guys have any idea the year or the mode from the photos.

Ignore the decals as I put them on myself. Serial is - gp101947

[image]

Comment: Hi Nathan, welcome to the site, as a general rule we don’t do valuations and serial numbers are few and far between and often don’t get great search results. If you only bought the bike a few months back then you know how much you paid so selling it on for either what you paid or a bit less isn’t a bad deal either way.

Answer (score 3):

It's a Giant Seek 1, maybe "Ltb" edition, circa 2011-2012. [Here's another one](https://www.pinkbike.com/buysell/1371631/).

Comment: Great spotting - the rear dropouts are quite unusual.  In that guise its very much a rigid commuter bike, not a MTB at all.